# One word for "embrace challenges"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Is there a single word to describe "embrace challenges"? The full context would be,

> A man who loves to [embrace challenges].

Comment: An "adventurer."

Comment: But an adventurer refers something about physical ones. Is there any alternative for this other than adventurer?

Comment: [Is this what you mean?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adventure_education)

Comment: I mean a person who works in an organization. He loves to embrace challenges in terms of his work. In this case, what do they call him/the work he does?

Comment: A real "go-getter."

Comment: Eager beaver, star doer, star dynamo, star fireball, star hustler, star pistol, star self-starter, star sharpy, star workhorse, star active person, star ambitious person, star ball of fire, star busy bee, star busy person, star hot shot, star live wire, no slouch, star spark plug

Comment: Voting to close as there is no context and example sentence in the question.

Comment: What, pray tell, is wrong with "embrace challenges"?

Comment: @HotLicks — Misuse of the word challenge?

Comment: @David - How do you think it's being misused?  "Challenge" can certainly be used as a noun.

Comment: @HotLicks — I was querying whether challenge was being used to mean problem. A question of taste rather than grammar.

Answer (score 1):

"He" is an "achiever", someone who loves to "achieve"

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite "one word", but a "**go-getter**" comes to mind: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/go-getter

I also tend to think that "**ambitious**" people do not shy away from challenges.
**Opportunistic** also comes to mind.

I know you asked for one word, but the person you are describing, I believe, is simultaneously an ambitious and opportunistic individual.